# PHP, why sometimes "\n or \r" works but sometimes doesnt?

Tags: php, string

Well, I am abit confuse using these \r,\n,\t etc things. Because I read online (php.net), it seems like works, but i try it, here is my simple code:

```
<?php
    $str   = "My name is jingle \n\r";
    $str2  = "I am a boy";

    echo $str . $str2;
?>
```

But the outcome is "My name is jingle I am a boy"

Either I put the \r\n in the var or in the same line as echo, the outcome is the same. Anyone knows why?

Comment: @Jingleboy- looking at this again, it looks like your "\n\r", is a typo. If you correct this it will then become more obvious that the problem is not using <pre></pre> tags or inserting a <br />.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because you are outputting to a browser, you need to use a `<br />` instead, otherwise wrap your output in `<pre>` tags.

Try:

```
<?php
    $str   = "My name is jingle <br />";
    $str2  = "I am a boy";

    echo $str . $str2;
?>
```

Or:

```
<?php
    $str   = "My name is jingle \n\r";
    $str2  = "I am a boy";

    echo '<pre>' .$str . $str2 . '</pre>';
?>
```

Browsers will not `<pre>serve` non-HTML formatting unless made explicit using `<pre>` - they are interested only in HTML.

Comment: This is a good answer, but having \n\r is bad as Jon points out.

Answer (score 4):

Well in your example you've got `\n\r` rather than `\r\n` - that's rarely a good idea.

Where are you seeing this outcome? In a web browser? In the source of a page, still in a web browser? What operating system are you using? All of these make a difference.

Different operating systems use different line terminators, and HTML/XML doesn't care much about line breaking, in that the line breaks in the source just mean "whitespace" (so you'll get a space between words, but not necessarily a line break).

Comment: LF is Unix-like and CR+LF is Windows. LF+CR is as Jingleboy99 has is just wrong.

Comment: LF = Line Feed (\n); CR = Carriage Return ('\r')

Answer (score 1):

You could also use nl2br():

```
echo nl2br($str . $str2);
```

What this function does is replace newline characters in your string to `<br`>.

Also, you don't need \r, just \n.

Answer (score 1):

Either use **\n** (*NIX) or **\r\n** (DOS / Windows), \n\r is very uncommon. Once you fix that, it should work just fine.

Of course, if you're outputting HTML, a line break does nothing unless it's inside <pre></pre> tags. Use <br /> to separate lines in HTML. The [nl2br()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function can help you to convert line breaks to HTML if needed.

Also, if you use single-quoted strings (your example has double quoted strings), \r and \n will not work. The only escape characters available in single quoted strings are ' and \.

Answer (score 1):

In [HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html), spaces, tabs, linefeeds and carriage returns are all equivalent white space characters.

In text, historically the following combinations have been used for [newlines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

- \r on Apple Macs
- \r\n on Windows
- \n on Unix

Answer (score 0):

Are you displaying the results in an HTML page? if so, HTML strips whitespace like newlines.  You'd have to something like use '<br />' instead of '/r/n' in HTML.